# Sidebar with collapsible individual items

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a standard HTML list with some menu items which will act as anchor links to various sections of a long scrolling page. I'd like to format it as a minimal vertical side navigation bar, where each item initially just shows a small coloured circle (but no text - sort of like traffic lights, but all the same colour), then when the user hovers over each circle, just that item's full text pops out to the side. I don't have direct access to the HTML as it's being generated by a 3rd party tool, but can use Javascript to access the DOM if needed.

The code I'm starting with looks something like:

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li><a href="#link1">Link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link2">Link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link3">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can find loads of examples where the whole side panel pops out - but not just the individual items. My main issue is I can't work out how to describe it to search for more information, so any pointers or suggestions would be welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Is the answer working for you?

Comment: Yes, this got me well on the way to solving it - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below perhaps:

```css
a {
 opacity: 0;
 transform: translateX(-100%);
 transition: all .3s ease;
 display: inline-block;
}

li:hover a {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navigation">
  <li><a href="#link1">Link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link2">Link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link3">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```